# How can I add a spellchecker to a Richtext box?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, spell-checking

How can I add a spellchecker to a richtextbox in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution. Hunspell is the spellcheck library Mozilla and OpenOffice.org uses. Its been ported to .NET as [NHunspell](http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net/), and is real easy to implement and has samples for you to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can purchase a spell checker control, integrate the Microsoft Office Spell Checker, write your own (which isn't too hard, actually, once you get the Soundex function figured out), or get a good free one.  Here's a (relatively) good free one.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/spellchecker_mg.aspx

For commercial products, I'd say to Google "Spell check WinForms"

If you're interested in rolling your own, I wrote one for Asp.Net back when I was in my beginner phase, and even then it only took me about a week to research and then a day or so to code.  It's a fun pet project.  I'd start by looking at soundex functions and comparing soundex values for similarity.

You start by comparing all of the words in the TextBox to a known dictionary, and using the soundex functions to come up with similar words.

From there, you can go on to creating a table for "popular replacements.  (for example, you can track that the word "teh" was replaced by "the" n times and move the more popular replacements to the top of the list.

Comment: That's funny!  But you're right.  I just fixed it.  Thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to hook into ASpell?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Google searches didn't turn up much, but this looks promising:  http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=354351